# My prefix is round

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> My prefix is round,
>
> My suffix eats birds,
>
> I come in many different colours,
>
> What am I?

---

This is my third non-math puzzle, so feel free to point out if there are any flaws!

Comment: Have to ask, having seen the accepted answer, what is going on with the suffix? How is it explained?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, what the heck, I’ll give it a shot with my original thought (and one shared by @Stiv and @Derek O):

My prefix is round,

> BALL, as previously discovered by Derek O, is round

My suffix eats birds,

> LOON: yes, the loon as in the bird doesn’t eat birds... but a loon is also a crazy person, and people definitely eat birds. This could be the reason for the wordplay tag, since I don’t see it used anywhere else in the puzzle.

I come in many different colours,

> Balloons come in many different colours

What am I?

> A BALLOON

Comment: Yeah, this is still all that's in my head... but that suffix...! :)

Comment: I guess a lunatic eats birds, anything from live birds - which is undoubtedly pretty crazy - to a piece of fried chicken! i didn't think this was the intention of the puzzle, but it seems like it might be... in retrospect, "ballcarrier" and my previous try "ballhawk" aren't totally convincing either.....

Comment: Yeah, totally understand both of your comments here, haha

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer might be

> Piebald

My prefix is round,

> Pie

My suffix eats birds,

> Bald (Eagle), the bird of prey

I come in different colours,

> Piebald = having irregular patches of two colours, typically black and white.

Comment: I added the "many" so that the last line becomes: "I come in many different colours"

Answer (score 1):

Are you a

> Bowl?

My prefix is round:

> According to OED, bow can mean "a curved stroke forming part of a letter (such as b or p)" or "a mental *ring* of scissors."

My suffix eats birds:

> Owls eat birds

I come in many colors:

> yes

Comment: Also incorrect.

Comment: Owls are birds of prey and they eat small mammals but they do not eat other birds.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not right . Still are you

> Circus ?

My prefix is round

> Cir means circle(which is round)

My suffix eats birds

> Us -> we eat bird(chicken ..etc)

I come in many different colours

> Circus is always colorful

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> ballcarrier [first attempt: ballhawk]

My prefix is round

> ball

My suffix eats birds

> carrier aircrafts can often "eat" birds by sucking them into their engines.... [hawks also eat birds]

I come in many different colors

> ballcarriers in American football come in many different colors, depending on the color of their team's jersey [ballhawks, those who make interceptions or steals in basketball, come in different colors depending on their team jersey]

Comment: Prefix correct!

Comment: I'll give it another shot!

Comment: I've been trying to make rot13(ONYYBBA) work for a few days now but can't for the life of me find a suitable suffix that 'eats birds'... Perhaps you can?

Comment: @Stiv https://dictionary.cambridge.org/zht/%E8%A9%9E%E5%85%B8/%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E/loon

Comment: @CulverKwan Indeed, but that eats fish not birds! :)

Comment: @CulverKwan I also thought of rot13(ybba) as a suffix, but they eat fish, crustaceans, and smaller amphibians and don't eat birds ([according to the Cornell Lab of Ornithology](https://www.allaboutbirds.org/guide/Common_Loon/lifehistory#food), the authoritative resource on birds) so I eliminated this as an answer. If rot13(onyybba) was your intended answer, I am afraid this is a flaw in the puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be

> Balladeer [Meaning here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/balladeer)

My prefix is round

> ball [Meaning here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ball) (ball is round)

My suffix eats birds

> deer [Meaning here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deer) [Instance of deer eating bird](https://www.fieldandstream.com/blogs/field-notes/researchers-document-deer-eating-birds/)

I come in many different colours

> Balladeer are humans so they can wear different coloured clothes and look colourful and so they can be said to come in many different colours.

Comment: I think it's a stretch to say that deer eat birds. Eating something opportunistically is different than regularly eating something.

Comment: The frequency of  'eating birds' is not mentioned in the question. @Derek O

Comment: I understand it's a technicality... but if someone asked you "do deer eat birds?" what would you say

Answer (score 1):

It could be a

> [Ball python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_python)

My prefix is round:

> Balls are round.

My suffix eats birds:

> Pythons feed mainly on mammals, birds, and other reptiles.

I come in many colors:

> Python breeders have developed many morphs with altered colors and patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Not a great answer

> Ballhawk

My prefix is round

> Ball is definitely round

My suffix eats bird

> According to a site on internet, hawk is a bird which eats small bird.(do correct me if I'm wrong)

I come in different colours

> Ballhawk Maryland Hat

Comment: No Problem! Welcome to Puzzling Stack Exchange!

Comment: By the way, thanks to @Derek O for giving all of us the prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Here goes nothing, are you a:

> peafowl

My prefix is round:

> peas are round

My suffix eats birds:

> owls eat birds. Although the actual prefix is 'fowl'

I come in many colors:

> peafowls (at least the males) are quite colorful

Comment: Fowl also eat birds! Wild fowl, in particular.

Comment: Owls do not eat birds

Comment: @AryanBeezadhur The Internet [begs to differ](https://www.owlpages.com/owls/articles.php?a=3)